# How to add a variable in `df2` that specify the number of rows of a specific level of a variable from `df1` using `dplyr` or `data.table`

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe `df1` that summarizes detections of a fish species over time thanks to the use of acoustic transmitters (attached to the fish) and acoustic receivers (placed in the area). Those transmitters have two sensors, one for measuring activity and other for measuring the fish depth. The transmitters only can send one kind of data (either activity or depth) at a time, and they send the signal every several minutes as a minimum. In the end, what we get is a dataframe with the time for the detection of a fish (`DateTime`), the receiver that detected the individual (`Receiver`), the transmitter that was detected (`Transmitter`) and also the type of info that the transmitter sent (`Sensor`). Below I show a reproducible example:

```
df1<-data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 12:04:07","2016-08-01 12:06:07","2016-08-01 13:12:12","2016-08-01 14:04:07","2016-08-01 15:01:45","2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 16:29:16","2016-08-01 16:33:16","2016-08-01 16:54:16","2016-08-01 16:58:16","2016-08-01 17:13:16","2016-08-01 17:21:16","2016-08-01 17:23:42","2016-08-01 17:27:16","2016-08-01 17:28:16","2016-08-01 17:29:28","2016-08-01 17:42:08"),
                Receiver=c( "V6", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V9", "V7", "V4" ),
                Transmitter=c(16 , 17, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 17),
                Sensor=c("Activity","Depth","Activity","Activity","Depth","Activity","Activity","Depth","Activity","Activity","Activity","Depth","Activity","Activity","Depth","Activity","Activity","Activity"))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")

df1

              DateTime Receiver Transmitter   Sensor
1  2016-08-01 12:04:07       V6          16 Activity
2  2016-08-01 12:06:07       V7          17    Depth
3  2016-08-01 13:12:12       V6          16 Activity
4  2016-08-01 14:04:07       V6          16 Activity
5  2016-08-01 15:01:45       V7          17    Depth
.            .                .           .       .
.            .                .           .       .
```

What I want is to create a dataframe `df2` in which I have this information arranged in a different way. I want to use hourly intervals in which each hour covers half an hour before and half an hour after (`RoundTime`). For every `RoundTime` I want for each transmitter (`Transmitter`) the number of times that was detected (`Num_det`), the number of different receivers that detected it (`Num_Rec`), the code of those receivers (`Which_Rec`), the number of detections with `Activity` info (`n_Activity`) and the number of detections with `Depth` info (`n_Depth`). I would expect this:

```
df2
             RoundTime Transmitter Num_det n_Activity n_Depth Num_Rec Which_Rec
1  2016-08-01 12:00:00          16       1          1       0       1        V6
2  2016-08-01 12:00:00          17       1          0       1       1        V7
3  2016-08-01 13:00:00          16       1          1       0       1        V6
4  2016-08-01 13:00:00          17       0          0       0      NA      <NA>
5  2016-08-01 14:00:00          16       1          1       0       1        V6
6  2016-08-01 14:00:00          17       0          0       0      NA      <NA>
7  2016-08-01 15:00:00          16       0          0       0      NA      <NA>
8  2016-08-01 15:00:00          17       1          0       1       1        V7
9  2016-08-01 16:00:00          16       2          1       1       2     V6 V7
10 2016-08-01 16:00:00          17       1          1       0       1        V6
11 2016-08-01 17:00:00          16       5          4       1       2     V6 V7
12 2016-08-01 17:00:00          17       4          3       1       3  V6 V7 V9
13 2016-08-01 18:00:00          16       0          0       0      NA      <NA>
14 2016-08-01 18:00:00          17       1          1       0       1        V4
```

So far I got `df2` with all the variables except `n_Activity` and `n_Depth`. Here I show the code and the result:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df2<-df1 %>% 
   # grouped by rounding the date by hour, Transmitter column
   group_by(RoundTime = round_date(DateTime, "hour"), Transmitter) %>% 
   # get the Num_det as number of rows, add more groups
   group_by(Num_det = n(), 
           which_Rec = toString(sort(unique(Receiver))), add = TRUE) %>%        
   # get the number of distinct elements of Receiver
   summarise(Num_Rec = n_distinct(Receiver)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   # expand the data to fill the missing combinations 
   complete(RoundTime, Transmitter, fill = list(Num_det = 0))%>% 
   select(RoundTime, Transmitter, Num_det, Num_Rec, which_Rec)

df2
# A tibble: 14 x 5
   RoundTime               Transmitter Num_det Num_Rec which_Rec 
   <dttm>                        <dbl>   <dbl>   <int> <chr>     
 1 2016-08-01 12:00:00.000          16       1       1 V6        
 2 2016-08-01 12:00:00.000          17       1       1 V7        
 3 2016-08-01 13:00:00.000          16       1       1 V6        
 4 2016-08-01 13:00:00.000          17       0      NA NA        
 5 2016-08-01 14:00:00.000          16       1       1 V6        
 6 2016-08-01 14:00:00.000          17       0      NA NA        
 7 2016-08-01 15:00:00.000          16       0      NA NA        
 8 2016-08-01 15:00:00.000          17       1       1 V7        
 9 2016-08-01 16:00:00.000          16       2       2 V6, V7    
10 2016-08-01 16:00:00.000          17       1       1 V6        
11 2016-08-01 17:00:00.000          16       5       2 V6, V7    
12 2016-08-01 17:00:00.000          17       4       3 V6, V7, V9
13 2016-08-01 18:00:00.000          16       0      NA NA        
14 2016-08-01 18:00:00.000          17       1       1 V4
```

Does anyone know which code I should add to the proposed before in order to create the variables `n_Activity` and `n_Depth`? If you know how to do it with the package `data_table` is even better since my real dataframe has millions of rows and `data.table` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need to do is count the number of "Activity" and "Depth" per group in your current code and I don't know why you have two `group_by` there.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(RoundTime = round_date(DateTime, "hour"), Transmitter) %>% 
  summarise(Num_det = n(), 
            which_Rec = toString(sort(unique(Receiver))),
            Num_Rec = n_distinct(Receiver), 
            n_Activity = sum(Sensor == "Activity"), 
            n_Depth = sum(Sensor == "Depth")) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   tidyr::complete(RoundTime, Transmitter, 
           fill = list(Num_det = 0, n_Activity = 0, n_Depth = 0))


# A tibble: 14 x 7
#   RoundTime           Transmitter Num_det which_Rec  Num_Rec n_Activity n_Depth
#   <dttm>                    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>        <int>      <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2016-08-01 12:00:00          16       1 V6               1          1       0
# 2 2016-08-01 12:00:00          17       1 V7               1          0       1
# 3 2016-08-01 13:00:00          16       1 V6               1          1       0
# 4 2016-08-01 13:00:00          17       0 NA              NA          0       0
# 5 2016-08-01 14:00:00          16       1 V6               1          1       0
# 6 2016-08-01 14:00:00          17       0 NA              NA          0       0
# 7 2016-08-01 15:00:00          16       0 NA              NA          0       0
# 8 2016-08-01 15:00:00          17       1 V7               1          0       1
# 9 2016-08-01 16:00:00          16       2 V6, V7           2          1       1
#10 2016-08-01 16:00:00          17       1 V6               1          1       0
#11 2016-08-01 17:00:00          16       5 V6, V7           2          4       1
#12 2016-08-01 17:00:00          17       4 V6, V7, V9       3          3       1
#13 2016-08-01 18:00:00          16       0 NA              NA          0       0
#14 2016-08-01 18:00:00          17       1 V4               1          1       0
```